# PRNG consistent across Java and Swift/Obj C

Tags: java, objective-c, swift, random

I need a psuedorandom number generator that is consistent across Java and Objective C.

I have plenty of experience with Java so I could implement a random number generator translated from some C library but I would struggle to do the same in Swift and also keep the output consistent with type conversions and such. Is there a simple random number generator that would be fairly easy to implement for a beginner Swift developer? or a library that produces the same results on both platforms?

Thanks.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/ :)

Comment: `Swift` natively supports interaction with `C` code, so if you have your PRNG in `C` you just use it. And and `C` code is 100% valid `ObjC` code, so there's no problem to use it from `ObjC` project too.

Comment: @user28434 good idea, thanks.